# How can I use MSBuild to delete all xml files, with the exception of those whose file names end in a certain manner?

Tags: msbuild

I have a build target called `CleanUp` which is responsible for deleting any files that are not required as part of the deployment of the build.

The step looks like this:

```
<Target Name="CleanUp">
  <Message Text="=== DELETING UNREQUIRED FILES ===" />
  <Delete Files="@(DeleteFromBuild)"/>
</Target>
```

My `DeleteFromBuild` Item Group contains this line:

```
<DeleteFromBuild Include="**\*.xml" Exclude="**\*.recipe.xml;**\*.NewRelic.xml;**\*PerformanceCounters.xml"/>
```

I would like to delete all xml files from my build, except for those that end either `.recipe.xml`, `.NewRelic.xml`, or `.PerformanceCounters.xml`. Unfortunately, all xml files are being removed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This seems correct, can you share the logfile? Maybe it gets deleted by the build server beofre build starts?

Comment: As Isantipov said, it all looks correct. If it **weren't** deleting any files I'd say move `DeleteFromBuild` definition inside the target as it's being evaluated too soon and doesn't match anything yet, may be move it anyway and run with `/v:diag` and have a look at the `Initial Items` log dumps.

Comment: Thanks for the comments- they have helped me to trace down the issue. It turned out that the xml files were actually not being deleted, but instead they were being excluded from being packaged by the nuspec file. I removed this exclude from the nuspec file and then moved the Item Group definition into the target and it worked fine. Thanks again.